# expect script stopped to after migration from Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04

Tags: mysql, expect

I have expect script that does backups.
It worked fine on different machines and OSes but it does not work on Ubuntu 12.04

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set folder [lindex $argv 0]
set password "PassWD"

spawn mysqldump -u root -p mydb01 --result-file=/home/myuser/backup/$folder/$
expect "*assword:"
send "$password\n";
#interact
wait
```

I tried to change `expect` line to

```
expect "Enter password:"
```

or

```
expect "Enter password: "
```

It does not work and it asks me to enter password like

```
Enter password:
```

I checked that mysql password is correct.

That script worked fine since 2010 on different OSes.

**UPDATE**

I created another cloud server with same OS and same data.
Everything works there. I have no idea why it does not work on first one.
I guess servers may have old commodity harddrives and it corrupted some file.

Comment: Did you try to run the command maually? This might help debugging.

Comment: BTW, `-p mydb01` looks weird to me. I guess the password is already assigned here so there is no prompt for entering password.

Comment: `-p mydb01` is not password. `mydb01` is databases name.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this,

```
expect "password"
```

or

```
expect -re ".*word"
```

Please make sure you are using the switch `'-re'` with expect when you want to use regular expressions.